# What infrastructures are required for airlines to send PNL messages?

Tags: airline-operations, passenger

There are lots of information about Type-B messages sent by airlines on IATA website but they have not stated under what communication systems (cable, teletype, intranet, internet, etc.) these messages are exchanged. What are these systems?

Comment: Proprietary networks, ARINC or SITA

Answer (score 2):

It's not just one. Private networks are used such as the IP-based ARINC AviNet, AFTN Teletype, etc.

For the specifics and standards, that information is not freely available (>\$3000). From [IATA manuals](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/standards-manuals.aspx), go to the Passenger tab, then the Security​ & Facilitation section. Or [click here](http://www.iata.org/publications/store/Pages/passenger-data-exchange.aspx).

> IATA's Passenger Data Exchange Support Plus package provides governments with all necessary standards, helpfully grouped in a single purchase.

The following example is [for France](https://pnr.gouv.fr/eng/content/download/430/3142/version/2/file/20160527_PNR_Guidelines+API-PNR+EN+V1+4.pdf) (may not be current):

---

[image]

There is also a [presentation](http://www.iata.org/iata/passenger-data-toolkit/presentation.html) on the IATA website you may want to download and check.